# How to ignore theorems when creating a pdf?

Tags: sectioning, pdf, automation, newtheorem

I am writing a document which includes exercises and their solution. To do distinguish them nicely, I used the amsthm package and the following code:

```
\newtheoremstyle{dotlessP}{}{}{\color{black}}{}{\color{red}\bfseries}{}{ }{}   
\newtheoremstyle{dotlessPP}{}{}{\color{black}}{}{\color{blue}\bfseries}{}{ }{}   
\theoremstyle{dotlessPP} \newtheorem{auf}{Aufgabe}[subsection]  
\theoremstyle{dotlessP} \newtheorem{loes}{Loesung}[subsection]
 
 \begin{loes}  
  Some Solutions
 \end{loes}
```

This did work out fine. However, I now would like to create a pdf where the solutions to the exercises are not included. Meaning, everything between \begin{loes} and \end{loes} should just be ignored. Is there an easy way to achive this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please tell us which theorem package you use: `amsthm`? `ntheorem`? something else?

Comment: You could use the environ package and ignore \BODY.  You could use `\begin{lrbox}{1} ... \end{lrbox}` and possibly a minipage.  To turn it on and off you would need a wrapper and \newif.  An MWE would be useful.

Comment: @Mico I'm using amsthm. Sorry that I forgot to add this in the original question...